# Show that $z$ is on the circle passing through $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ if and only if [$z$, $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$] is real or ∞

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ are distinct points in $\hat{\mathbb {C}}$ . Show that $z$ is on the circle passing through $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ if and only if [$z$, $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$] is real or ∞.

Comment: A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka ?

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch:**

1. Möbius transformations preserve the cross-ratio,
   $$ [z,z_1,z_2,z_3]=[T(z),T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3)]. $$
2. There is a Möbius transformation sending $z_1 \mapsto 0$, $z_2 \mapsto 1$, $z_3 \mapsto \infty$.
3. Since Möbius transformations are bijective and map circles to circles, $w$ is on the real line (${}\cup \{\infty\}$) if and only if $z$ is on the circle through $z_1,z_2,z_3$.
4. $[w,0,1,\infty]=w$ (or $1/w$ or $1-w$ or some composition thereof, depending on the definition). Hence the cross-ratio is real iff $w$ is real or $\infty$, which proves what you want.

Comment: Chappers, [Why is w real if z is on the circle through z1,z2,z3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865256/why-is-w-real-if-z-is-on-the-circle-through-z-1-z-2-z-3), $w=T(z)$? It seems you proved cross ratio is real iff z is on the circle. But what about real or ∞ iff z is on the circle ?

Comment: @BCLC There's a reason it says "sketch". Möbius transformations are bijective on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, so $w$ could only be $\infty$ if it's one of the three points we already know are on the circle.

Comment: thanks so much! ^-^

Comment: I think I got it. Is my answer wrong please?