# Complex numbers on quadrilateral in cyclic order

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4 ∈$ $\mathbb{C}$ such that these numbers are in quadrilateral appear in a cyclic and positive order, prove that these numbers are contained in a circumference if and only if:

$$(\frac{z_1 - z_2}{z_3 - z_2})(\frac{z_3 - z_4}{z_1 - z_4}) < 0$$

So, so far I have tried to prove this using geometry and tried some theorems of complex numbers, but since we only started to see complex numbers about one and a half week, I don't have a great knowledge about complex numbers.

By doing a little bit of research I find that this problem has to see a bit with Ptolemy's theorem. Am I rigth?

I also don't have seen Euler's, can you help me?

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article on [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) helpful.

Comment: Here it is partially solved https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676067/complex-numbers-z-1-z-2-z-3-and-z-4-lie-on-a-circle-show-w-fracz

Comment: @user376343 I understand, but how I arrive to say that the cross ratio is negative?

Comment: The angles are oriented, and their orientation is opposite to that of the points. Draw a picture to see it.

Comment: Yes, so these 4 points conclyc, so the angles are suplemenatry

Comment: So then $arg((\frac{z_1 - z_2}{z_3 - z_2})(\frac{z_3 - z_4}{z_1 - z_4}))$ = $0$ or $π$