# When is $(z_1 - z_2)(z_3 - z_4)$ a negative real number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When is $(z_1 - z_2)(z_3 - z_4)$ a negative real number? I know that for this number to be real, then its imaginary part must be 0; however, for the real part, I get

$$ax - aw - cx + cw + by - bz - dy + dz.$$

How do I know when this is negative? I need this in order to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695734/complex-numbers-on-quadrilateral-in-cyclic-order?noredirect=1#comment7595458_3695734).

Comment: Can you explain where this expression comes from? I understand that you have expressed each of these complex numbers in the form $z = a + bi,$ but can you explicitly write down which one is which? I believe that there is an easier way to figure this out.

Comment: Treat them as complex vectors. You want their product to be $ r Cis (\pi )$. What does that tell you about their angles?

Comment: @Carlo $z_1 = a + bi$ $z_2 = c + di$ $z_3 = x + yi$ $z_4 = w + zi$

Comment: @CalvinLin that they suplementary